# Python regular expression: about getting text

Tags: python

i'm trying to make a teleport module for a game but first i have to get coordinates from ListBoxEx

```
self.Gui[3].AppendItem(Item(str(chr.GetNameByVID(i)) + "    " + str(nonplayer.GetLevelByVID(i)) + "    " + "%d, %d" % (mobX/100, mobY/100)))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX8aV.jpg

i tried this

```
mob_x, mob_y = re.findall(r"\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)", item_index.GetText())[0]
```

result: Index error

```
    def Teleport(self):
    item_index = self.Gui[3].GetSelectedItem() 
    if not item_index: 
        chat.AppendChat(chat.CHAT_TYPE_INFO, "Kein Item ausgewählt!") 
        return 
    mob_x, mob_y = re.findall(r"\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)", item_index.GetText())[0]  

    chr.SetPixelPosition(mob_x, mob_y)
```

Comment: Can you please copy a sample of the text you'd like to parse with the regex?

Comment: The index error means you get an empty list back, ie it matched nothing.

Comment: You could have edited your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot your text is something like "108, 109" but reqular expression is parsing "(108, 109)". Use:

```
mob_x, mob_y = re.findall(r"([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)", item_index.GetText())[0]
```